# how can I use constraints on a group of elements in storyboard in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

in my `UIStoryBoard` I have the following situation:

[image]

a `UIViewController` with two elements - a button and a label.
Text on each component is fetched from localized.strings, so it has different length each time user chooses different language.
In the code I have:

```
myButton.setTitle("TextOnButton".localized(), for: .normal)
myButton.sizeToFit()
txtLabel.text = "txt".localized()
```

how should I attach constraints so that those two elements - when grouped together - are always in the center? For example:

this is not in the middle:

[image]

this is in the middle:

[image]

If it was only one element, I would attach constraint `midX` and that's all, but what about the situation when there are two elements? can I just - somehow - attach constraints to group of elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that with help of something called `Stack View`. In the StoryBoard select both labels and click the following button: 
[image: StackViewButton]

In the hierarchy you will notice that both labels got wrapped inside a `Stack View`. Now you just have to add the `Horizontally in Container`and `Vertically in Container`constraints to the stack view. Finally you can add some `Spacing` between the two labels in the attribute inspector when the `stack view` is selected.
Finally result:
[image: Final result]

Comment: hm that looks really fine, however when I added those two elements like you wrote (and I did exactly what you said) - suddenly the stack go huge... when I went to properties I saw this: http://imgur.com/sXDPKWL It looks to me like an xcode bug, I cannot change this value... it's xcode 8.1

Comment: That is a bit weird because the stack view normally makes the size of the labels `fit to content`. Anyway, add some with and hight constraints to the `stack view`or/and the two labels and you should be good. <br>